# Cant connect school projector on Lenovo thinkpad L450 (ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga

I've searched on Google and tested many things but I cant get my VGA port to work. I am trying to connect to an EPSON projector but it won't even say its connected.

Here is the output from command `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Can you see it in System Settings > Screen Display when the projector is on?

Comment: nope, It doesn't come up there ether.

Comment: What GPU/CPU are you running, and have you installed correct drivers? `xrandr` doesn't show VGA output anywhere :/

Comment: I got Intel Inside Core i5 and Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500